# Como convertir correctamente mi componente en uno generico que tome datos que reciba de un array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Tengo este componente que muestra el resumen de una venta pero ahora tengo que hacer que el componente sea genérico o sea este componente debe recibir un array de objetos.

mi componente actual:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="row col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <table class="table col-sm-4">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ subtotal | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Descuento</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ discount | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Envío</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ shipping | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Impuesto</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ taxes | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
          <th class="total">{{ total | currency }}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'w-purchase-summary-table',
  props: {
    subtotal: Number,
    discount: Number,
    shipping: Number,
    taxes: Number,
    total: Number
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Tiene que recibir un array para que no sea solo para ventas sino este tipo de componente pero general para poder utilizar en otras pantallas.

*Entonces:*

Como convertir correctamente mi componente en uno generico que tome datos que reciba de un array?

Comment: Y cual seria el problema que tenes en hacerlo generico?

Comment: Si, como convertir correctamente mi componente en uno generico que tome datos que reciba de un array. @gbianchi gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas recibir y como querrias renderizarlo? Porque no entiendo donde particularmente tenes el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recibir un array como propiedad del componente, se hace de la siguiente manera: 

HTML

```
<w-purchase-summary-table :myNewArray = "[
        {name: 'Person Name', isSortable: true}, 
        {name: 'Country', isSortable: true}]"
    ></w-purchase-summary-table>
```

VUEJS

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'w-purchase-summary-table',
  props: {
    subtotal: Number,
    discount: Number,
    shipping: Number,
    taxes: Number,
    total: Number, 
    myNewArray: []
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné utilizando v-for de la siguiente manera:

```
<template>
  <styleGuideSection-view title="Tabla de resumen de venta">
    <b-container fluid>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <w-purchase-summary-table 
          v-for="item in items" 
          :key="item.message">
          {{ items.message}} 
          </w-purchase-summary-table>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <p class="bigger bold">Implementación</p>
          <code>
            <pre>
              &lt;w-purchase-summary-table 
                &nbsp;v-for="item in items" 
                &nbsp;:key="item.message">
                &lt;/w-purchase-summary-table&gt;
            </pre>
          </code>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </styleGuideSection-view>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'table-guide',
  components: {
    'styleGuideSection-view': styleGuideSection,
    'w-purchase-summary-table': purchaseSummaryTable
  },
  data () {
    return {
       items: [
        {message: 'subtotal' , value: '100'},
        ]
    }
  },
}
```